# Menulist Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

any one can tell how can i load list of files from a folder into a Menulist using JavaScript Arrays.

Comment: a MenuList? is this a javascript list of files? What have you already tried? What I'm saying is that you will get a lot better help with some explanation and background.

Comment: you problably can't. javascript can't access files for security reasons.

Comment: In fact i'm working on a firefox extension development. I want to list all files in a folder in the xul menu list. I thought of doing it using JS but I can't because of security reasons. Now i would like to know how we can link java class in JS in XUL firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleave it is possible only using ActiveX Object, which is supported by IE only. Here You can find some tutorials: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/144152 .

If You are making something for internal use, than You might consider using ActiveX Object. Otherwise, not possible with JS, unfortunately - use server-side languages.\

Example of listing all files in a directory with Java:

```
import java.io.File;
  public class ListFiles { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      // Directory path here
      String path = "."; 

      String files;
      File folder = new File(path);
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

      for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
          files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
          System.out.println(files);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You can then output the files to the webpage with what ever method You are using.

Comment: Is there any way to do it using java and link with JS.

Comment: Does it work with firefox browser 'cause i would like to open a folder from xul firefox.

Comment: Hi by any chance do you have a sample code which explains how to call a java class in JS in a HTML file?

Comment: In fact i'm working on a firefox extension development. I want to list all files in a folder in the xul menu list. I thought of doing it using JS but I can't because of security reasons. Now i would like to know how we can link java class in JS in XUL firefox. Even if u have any example using java class in JS is highly appreciated and it'll be more helpful to me. Thanking you;